# Tensorflow export strategy input function for bow_encoder

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement serving function to be able to make predictions on saved text classification model. As I understood the goal is to create a function which will do almost exactly same as train_input_fn/eval_input_fn? I have following implementation of those functions:

```
def generate_training_input_fn(filename):
  train_raw = pd.read_csv(filename[0], header=None)

  x_train = train_raw.iloc[:, 1]
  y_train = train_raw.iloc[:, 0]

  vocab_processor = tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH)
  x_train = np.array(list(vocab_processor.fit_transform(x_train)))

  n_words = len(vocab_processor.vocabulary_)
  #print('Total words: %d' % n_words)

# Save a vocabulary list to file. Needed by the serving_input_fn for exporting the model.

 with open('vocab_processor.pickle', 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump(vocab_processor, f)

  features = tf.contrib.layers.bow_encoder(
      x_train, vocab_size=n_words, embed_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE)

  return features, y_train

def generate_eval_input_fn(filename):
  eval_raw = pd.read_csv(filename[0], header=None)

  x_eval = eval_raw.iloc[:, 1]
  y_eval = eval_raw.iloc[:, 0]

  with open('vocab_processor.pickle', 'rb') as f:
      vocab_processor = pickle.load(f)
  n_words = len(vocab_processor.vocabulary_)
  x_eval = np.array(list(vocab_processor.transform(x_eval)))

  features = tf.contrib.layers.bow_encoder(
      x_eval, vocab_size=n_words, embed_dim=EMBEDDING_SIZE)
#labels = tf.one_hot(y_eval, 15, 1, 0)

  return features, y_eval
```

There is comment "Save a vocabulary list to file. Needed by the serving_input_fn for exporting the model" but there is no such function  implemented and Experiment is created with export_strategies=None  ( got this code from another coder ). I've tried to implement serving_input_fn like in census tutorial

```
def csv_serving_input_fn():
  csv_row = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.string)
  features = parse_csv(csv_row)

  return tf.contrib.learn.InputFnOps(features, None, {'csv_row': csv_row})
```

but have no idea how to implement parse_csv since my generate_eval_input_fn takes whole csv as pandas DataFrame